# How to use JavaScript in Node-red to display message based on dropdown options

Tags: javascript, node-red

Given this Node-red flow:

[image]

I am unfortunately unsure about how I should implement it in function.

I have 3 options in both dropdowns, one displaying *meattype* the other *doneness*. Whenever I choose a combination of the dropdowns, I should have the proper temperature given in the text output.

I have tried using `If`, but I still have problems with getting it to work.

I only have very basic knowledge of Javascript language, so I hope someone could help and at least lead me in the right direction.

Thank you

EDIT:
In the `If` code in my function node I had "A conditional expression" present, though I got this fixed by changing `If` from:

`if(msg.payload = "")`

to

`if(msg.payload == "")`

This fixed my code and gave me the expected results.

`var payload = msg.payload`

`if(msg.payload == "KalvRoed"){`

`msg.temperature = "53-57 grader"}`

Comment: There isn't really enough information about what you are trying to do here. Also we would need to see the output from the join node to know where to start. You should have that from the attached debug node. Edit the question to add more detail, what you've already tried and the debug out.

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you've tried. Also please read the doc on what a good Stack Overflow question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have a solution DO NOT edit the question to include it. Add it as a real answer then you can mark it as accepted, which will make it easier to find for others. (And don't post images of code, post the actual code and format it properly using the toolbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had "A conditional expression" which means I had to change my code, so that "if" was written with "==" rather than "=". If "if" had been written with "=" the function node would think that I was creating a variable, while I was trying to have it do something if  was true.

`var payload = msg.payload`

`if(msg.payload == "KalvRoed"){`

`msg.temperature = "53-57 grader"}`

Hope that makes sense